# How to convert a Class object of a given Java base type to a DataType of Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

How to convert a Class object of a given Java base type to a DataType of Flink?
Just like this：

```
    public static RowType convert(Class<?> pojo) {
        ...
    }

    Field[] fields = pojo.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
            continue;
        }
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        DataType fieldType = convertToDataType(field.getType());
        RowType.RowField rowField = new RowType.RowField(fieldName, fieldType.getLogicalType());
        rowFields.add(rowField);
    }
```

I couldn't find any relevant methods for conversion in Flink's built-in functions.
Can I only write my own method in this situation? Just like this：

```
private static DataType convertToDataType(Class<?> clazz) {
        if (clazz == CharSequence.class) {
            return DataTypes.STRING();
        }
        if (clazz == String.class) {
            return DataTypes.STRING();
        }
        if (clazz == int.class || clazz == Integer.class) {
            return DataTypes.INT();
        }
        ...
}
```